# Which one is correct: "communications device" or "communication device"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is there any difference between "wireless communications device" and "wireless communication device"? Which one would be more appropriate in the following title:

> Motion programming of spatial manipulator using wireless
>   communication(s) device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are used, but the singular *commmunication* as the attributive modifier [is more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=communication%20device,communications%20device&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than the plural *communications*.